# Getting SetSpeechProperty to work with kSpeechCurrentVoiceProperty

Tags: macos, text-to-speech

I am trying to figure out what the dictionary used in a `SetSpeechProperty` call for the `kSpeechCurrentVoiceProperty` is supposed to contain. I have tried every method I could think of to figure this out, but I have been unsuccessful thus far. The documentation for this (as of 10.8) doesn’t say.

Here is a code example of what I am trying to do:

```
OSStatus err = noErr;

SpeechChannel speechChannel = NULL;
NewSpeechChannel(NULL, &speechChannel);

id voiceID = ???; // From the crashes I got, I assume that this should be a NS/CFNumber.
id voiceCreator = ???;

CFDictionaryRef voiceDict = (CFDictionaryRef)@{
(NSString *)kSpeechVoiceID : voiceID,
(NSString *)kSpeechVoiceCreator : voiceCreator
};

err = SetSpeechProperty(speechChannel, kSpeechCurrentVoiceProperty, voiceDict);
```

In theory, I could do something like this, of course:

```
VoiceSpec voice;
GetIndVoice(voiceNum, &voice);
NewSpeechChannel(&voice, &chan);
```

For very complicate reasons this is not an option in my specific case. In actuality, I get the speechChannel from somewhere else that I don’t have control over and I can’t replace it with another one. So I have to modify it in situ.

Save me from this valley of under documented madness, please!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (from an updated [CocoaSpeechSynthesisExample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaSpeechSynthesisExample/)):

```
// Update our object fields with the selection
fSelectedVoiceCreator = theVoiceSpec.creator;
fSelectedVoiceID = theVoiceSpec.id;

// Change the current voice.  If it needs another engine, then dispose the current channel and open another
NSDictionary *voiceDict = @{(__bridge NSString *)kSpeechVoiceID:@(fSelectedVoiceID),
                            (__bridge NSString *)kSpeechVoiceCreator:@(fSelectedVoiceCreator)};

theErr = SetSpeechProperty(fCurSpeechChannel, kSpeechCurrentVoiceProperty, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) voiceDict);
if (incompatibleVoice == theErr) {
    theErr = [self createNewSpeechChannel:&theVoiceSpec];
}
```